# Unity iOS Crash : JobQueue::WaitForJobGroupID(JobGroupID, JobQueue::JobQueueWorkStealMode)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, mobile, crash

Recently, we upgraded our Unity version from 2021.3.11 to 2021.3.27, and we started experiencing significant crashes on iOS. The crash-free rate dropped from 99.5% to 93%. Our project includes Adjust, GameAnalytics, FacebookSDK, Firebase, and ApplovinMax plugins. In the latest update, we only updated Unity and a few mediation networks within ApplovinMax. I'm also sharing the stack trace

We are not sure if this issue is related to the Unity version, as we have been unable to reproduce it on our own devices.

Do you have any idea what is happening

```
Native StackTrace:

Thread 0 (crashed)
0   UnityFramework                     0x00000001093fd898 JobQueue::WaitForJobGroupID(JobGroupID, JobQueue::JobQueueWorkStealMode) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Jobs/Internal/JobQueue.cpp:1750)
1   UnityFramework                     0x00000001093f9408 CompleteFenceInternal(JobFence&, WorkStealMode) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Jobs/Jobs.cpp:17)
2   UnityFramework                     0x00000001098bb57c GeometryJobTasks::PutGeometryJobTask(GfxDevice&, GeometryJobTasks::GeometryJobTask*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Jobs/Jobs.h:282)
3   UnityFramework                     0x00000001098bb4a0 GeometryJobTasks::EndFrame(GfxDevice&) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Include/Cpp/mpsc_node_stack.h:65)
4   UnityFramework                     0x00000001098bb248 GeometryJobTasks::Flush(GfxDevice&) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/GfxDevice/GeometryJob.cpp:49)
5   UnityFramework                     0x00000001098e3c78 DestroyGfxDevice() (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/GfxDevice/GfxDevice.cpp:222)
6   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109a1ac7c UnityCleanup (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/LibEntryPoint.mm:212)
7   UnityFramework                     0x0000000107b5ac54 -[UnityAppController applicationWillTerminate:] (/Users/oguzthedeveloper/UnityProjects/Builds/DrillTheGame/iOs/Release/1-10-05/Classes/UnityAppController.mm:533)
8   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d427cfc0 <symbols missing for uuid: b3834960244b34e49ea0ca4bb44ef0f3> 
9   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d37b6018 <symbols missing for uuid: b3834960244b34e49ea0ca4bb44ef0f3> 
10  UIKitCore                          0x00000001d3bcea94 <symbols missing for uuid: b3834960244b34e49ea0ca4bb44ef0f3> 
11  UIKitCore                          0x00000001d4279408 <symbols missing for uuid: b3834960244b34e49ea0ca4bb44ef0f3> 
12  FrontBoardServices                 0x00000001e754c51c <symbols missing for uuid: 11a9f887776b31e985578a24a587dd1b> 
13  FrontBoardServices                 0x00000001e751105c <symbols missing for uuid: 11a9f887776b31e985578a24a587dd1b> 
14  FrontBoardServices                 0x00000001e754c4bc <symbols missing for uuid: 11a9f887776b31e985578a24a587dd1b> 
15  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001d898aeac <symbols missing for uuid: bb347f0ef21c360782e6c8d750fdbf8c> 
16  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001d898e91c <symbols missing for uuid: bb347f0ef21c360782e6c8d750fdbf8c> 
17  FrontBoardServices                 0x00000001e751b188 <symbols missing for uuid: 11a9f887776b31e985578a24a587dd1b> 
18  FrontBoardServices                 0x00000001e751ad24 <symbols missing for uuid: 11a9f887776b31e985578a24a587dd1b> 
19  FrontBoardServices                 0x00000001e751d5d0 <symbols missing for uuid: 11a9f887776b31e985578a24a587dd1b> 
20  CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d158e128 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
21  CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d159a7b4 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
22  CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d151f648 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
23  CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d15350d4 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
24  CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
25  GraphicsServices                   0x000000020c9d735c <symbols missing for uuid: e830ad84d6123b6b8de7ea61a786d132> 
26  UIKitCore                          0x00000001d38c76e8 <symbols missing for uuid: b3834960244b34e49ea0ca4bb44ef0f3> 
27  UIKitCore                          0x00000001d38c734c <symbols missing for uuid: b3834960244b34e49ea0ca4bb44ef0f3> 
28  UnityFramework                     0x0000000107b5e820 -[UnityFramework runUIApplicationMainWithArgc:argv:] (/Users/oguzthedeveloper/UnityProjects/Builds/DrillTheGame/iOs/Release/1-10-05/Classes/main.mm:96)
29  DrillTheGame                    0x0000000100353c00 main (/Users/ekici/Documents/UnityProjects2/drill-the-game/Builds/iOS/d1/MainApp/main.mm:28)
30  Unknown                            0x00000001f0a12dec <unknown> 

Thread 1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc00 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001d898bafc <symbols missing for uuid: bb347f0ef21c360782e6c8d750fdbf8c> 
2   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109bbce0c UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire(UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Handle) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Source/Darwin/Baselib_SystemSemaphore_DarwinApi.inl.h:37)
3   UnityFramework                     0x000000010940dda0 AGCThread::Run() (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Include/C/Internal/Baselib_Semaphore_SemaphoreBased.inl.h:0)
4   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109415574 AGCThread::RunThread(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Misc/GarbageCollectSharedAssets.cpp:232)
5   UnityFramework                     0x00000001094a04c8 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Threads/Thread.cpp:82)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 2
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc00 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001d898bafc <symbols missing for uuid: bb347f0ef21c360782e6c8d750fdbf8c> 
2   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109bbce0c UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire(UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Handle) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Source/Darwin/Baselib_SystemSemaphore_DarwinApi.inl.h:37)
3   UnityFramework                     0x000000010940dda0 AGCThread::Run() (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Include/C/Internal/Baselib_Semaphore_SemaphoreBased.inl.h:0)
4   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109415574 AGCThread::RunThread(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Misc/GarbageCollectSharedAssets.cpp:232)
5   UnityFramework                     0x00000001094a04c8 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Threads/Thread.cpp:82)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 3
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc00 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001d898bafc <symbols missing for uuid: bb347f0ef21c360782e6c8d750fdbf8c> 
2   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109bbce0c UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire(UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Handle) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Source/Darwin/Baselib_SystemSemaphore_DarwinApi.inl.h:37)
3   UnityFramework                     0x000000010940dda0 AGCThread::Run() (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Include/C/Internal/Baselib_Semaphore_SemaphoreBased.inl.h:0)
4   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109415574 AGCThread::RunThread(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Misc/GarbageCollectSharedAssets.cpp:232)
5   UnityFramework                     0x00000001094a04c8 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Threads/Thread.cpp:82)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 4
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc00 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001d898bafc <symbols missing for uuid: bb347f0ef21c360782e6c8d750fdbf8c> 
2   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109bbce0c UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire(UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Handle) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Source/Darwin/Baselib_SystemSemaphore_DarwinApi.inl.h:37)
3   UnityFramework                     0x000000010940dda0 AGCThread::Run() (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Include/C/Internal/Baselib_Semaphore_SemaphoreBased.inl.h:0)
4   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109415574 AGCThread::RunThread(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Misc/GarbageCollectSharedAssets.cpp:232)
5   UnityFramework                     0x00000001094a04c8 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Threads/Thread.cpp:82)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 5
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc00 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00000001d898bafc <symbols missing for uuid: bb347f0ef21c360782e6c8d750fdbf8c> 
2   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109bbce0c UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire(UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Handle) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Source/Darwin/Baselib_SystemSemaphore_DarwinApi.inl.h:37)
3   UnityFramework                     0x000000010940dda0 AGCThread::Run() (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/External/baselib/builds/Include/C/Internal/Baselib_Semaphore_SemaphoreBased.inl.h:0)
4   UnityFramework                     0x0000000109415574 AGCThread::RunThread(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Misc/GarbageCollectSharedAssets.cpp:232)
5   UnityFramework                     0x00000001094a04c8 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Threads/Thread.cpp:82)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 6
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2fd4 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
7   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2ebc <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
8   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d39fa3fc <symbols missing for uuid: b3834960244b34e49ea0ca4bb44ef0f3> 
9   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 7
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210400558 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   JavaScriptCore                     0x00000001e4d038ac <symbols missing for uuid: c9852269bf5a3150afed2d50892b6d4b> 
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 8
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d157cea4 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
7   CoreMotion                         0x00000001dcabe248 <symbols missing for uuid: 30e3286cf5fc3655a5c0d8604de58645> 
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 9
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   CFNetwork                          0x00000001d2725580 <symbols missing for uuid: 6aafe7c4f1c43020ad1670591c86d7b0> 
7   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 10
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   FirebaseCrashlytics                0x00000001030e4de8 <symbols missing for uuid: aecd52272f233a6fb2baa438a4a18a5b> 
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 11
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2fd4 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
7   UnityFramework                     0x0000000107f0b178 -[AdColony workerSetup] 
8   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 12
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2fd4 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
7   UnityFramework                     0x0000000107e9db18 -[ADCODTThread main] 
8   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 13
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2fd4 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
7   UnityFramework                     0x0000000107e9db18 -[ADCODTThread main] 
8   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 14
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2fd4 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
7   UnityFramework                     0x0000000107e9db18 -[ADCODTThread main] 
8   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 15
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2fd4 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
7   UnityFramework                     0x0000000107e9db18 -[ADCODTThread main] 
8   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 16
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2fd4 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
7   UnityFramework                     0x0000000107e9db18 -[ADCODTThread main] 
8   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 17
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2fd4 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
7   UnityFramework                     0x0000000107e9db18 -[ADCODTThread main] 
8   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 18
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2fd4 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
7   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7c2e68 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
8   UnityFramework                     0x0000000108e5d4bc -[PAGThreadMonitor threadEntryPoint:] (/var/folders/t9/7pcld_8n6px6s6xkqsd62bfm0000gv/T/cocoapods-yqb0ktmg/Pods/PAGAdSDK/PAGAdSDK/PAGAdSDK/PAGAdSDK/Service/Monitor/PAGThreadMonitor.m:30)
9   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 19
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002103ffc84 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x0000000210412e2c <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104001c8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
3   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1534024 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
4   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d1535250 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
5   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d153a3ec <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
6   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d157cea4 <symbols missing for uuid: 4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> 
7   UnityFramework                     0x0000000108bd1114 -[PAGAdPCMThreadManager task] (/var/folders/t9/7pcld_8n6px6s6xkqsd62bfm0000gv/T/cocoapods-yqb0ktmg/Pods/PAGAdSDK/PAGAdSDK/PAGAdSDK/PAGAdSDK/BUAdEventTrack/Private/BUAdPCMTrack/PAGAdPCMThreadManager.m:94)
8   Foundation                         0x00000001cb7dc544 <symbols missing for uuid: 6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> 
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

Thread 20
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00000002104007e8 <symbols missing for uuid: 75da6452934e3f80b181d47074378e83> 
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123d6b8 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x000000023123cb88 <symbols missing for uuid: 56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> 

...
```